# Return value from ProwerShell to Registry HKLM: Access Denied

Tags: powershell, registry, registrykey

**Old Issue:** I'm trying to write a script in cmd where PS script sets the system format date as current date.....

::::::::::Edit
**New Issue:**
I made a bit of advancement. Now that I've more on completely to PowerShell here is the code:

```
$a=get-date -UFormat "%s"
<# $env:ElDate = ''
Set-Item -Path Env:\ElDate -Value (get-date -UFormat "%s") #>
$HxVal= [System.Convert]::ToString($a,16) <# '{0:x}' -f $a #>
Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion' -Name InstallDate -Value $HxVal
reg add 'HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion' /v InstallDate /d $HxVal /f
return $HxVal
```

But I'm getting this.

```
Set-ItemProperty: D:\Download\Scripts\test\GetCDate.ps1:5:1
Line |
   5 |  Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVe … 
     |  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~   
     | Requested registry access is not allowed.

ERROR: Access is denied.
6267ab4f
```

How do I write in LocalMachine? Can anyone Help?

Regards,

Comment: Why use powershell script, just call it once off `for /f "delims=" %%a in ('powershell "$a=get-date -UFormat "%s";$env:ElDate = '';Set-Item -Path Env:\ElDate -Value (get-date -UFormat "%s");return $a"') do echo %%a`

Comment: I tried but the output is the same as before "Echo is on"

Comment: Yes. Because you set `%$ElDt%` but echo `%ElDt%`

Comment: You need to elevate, _(Run as administrator)_, your script, if you wish to make changes to the Local Machine registry.

Comment: Well, now you have changed the scope of the question entirely andwe are sittingwith a debug request.

Comment: How do I close this request?

Comment: you can delete it. just below the tags is an `delete` button.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone! I found the solution. Its just that I was aiming so high that I didn't see besides me. A very simple "Back To School" solution did it.

Run PowerShell as Administrator and execute the ps1 script in it. Now I just have to find an app that'll create its exe in administrative privileges.

> Note: In actual this scrips sets the current date as Install date in
> Window Registry that can be accessed through **WMIC OS**. We usually
> install windows via images and that sets the install date as the same
> date the image was created. So in any case, anyone formatting through
> image and not informing should go in the Non-Compliance part wherein
> all the 1000+ Servers had the same date. this code can be pushed
> through GP for the first time or added to the scripts that are
> required to finalize the Server after image restoration.

Regards,